# Issue with Firefox mixed content blocker

Tags: firefox, https, hugo

I have access to my university server. I am trying to deploy a static website (created by hugo) on this server.

When I try to view this website on firefox the main index page (say `https://blah.edu/abc`) renders fine. Next when I click to a hyperlinked page (say `https://blah.edu/abc/foo`) the css  on foo is not rendered. Investigating with the firefox web developer inspector tool the problem on the foo page seems to be due to *mixed content blocker*.

Trying this again, with the inspector tool on, I note that firefox tries to access `https://blah.edu/abc` via `GET https://blah.edu/abc`... but it uses **`GET http://blah.edu/abc/foo`** to get the foo page.

I am using `https' in my baseurl (in hugo configuration) and everything works fine in the Hugo server, so I am confused why this is happening.

Any hints or help is greatly appreciated.

The same site works perfectly on Midori browser.

Thank you!

Comment: You obviously have a reference to the HTTP variant somewhere in your setup. Try grepping for it?